# Calendar icon becomes hidden after changing slotProps in the latest MUI Date Pickers

Tags: material-ui

I recently upgraded **@mui/x-date-pickers** to **6.0.1**. After that changing **texfield** style through **slotProps** makes calendar icon hide in date picker.

I even tried to set **openPickerIcon** in **slots** props, but the icon remain hidden. Can anyone please help me in this regards?

Please check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-ully-k4hjsh).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can show the icon with your custom css like this:

```
<Box p="20px">
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
    <DatePicker />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <DatePicker
      slotProps={{
        textField: {
          classes: {
            root: "inputPadding"
          }
        }
      }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
</Box>
```

And your custom css should be like this:

```
.inputPadding input {
  padding: 11px;
}
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-calendar-icon-fix?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.